# How to ignore same page in navigation history

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

Is there anyway that we can ignore same page entry in navigation stack,
Actually I have a following situation in my UWP App, this is how user is navigating from one page to another

MainPage - > Page 1 -> Page 2 - >

Now from Splitview user click on Page 1, and so stack goes like this

MainPage -> Page 1 - > Page 2 -> Page 1

What I want is that if Page 1 is already loaded than I want to remove Page 1 and all the Frame above that page,

This is what stack should look like:

MainPage -> Page 1

In android I know that we can set flag "ClearTop" so that it automatically performs clean up for the same page, is there something like that for UWP App?

Answer (score 0):

On the current frame, you can check the BackStack collection, and remove any entry

Here is a snippet you can use, and adapt :)

```
     Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        if (rootFrame.CanGoBack)
        {
            // Check if we are on the entry page and try to go back
            var backTypePage = rootFrame.BackStack[rootFrame.BackStackDepth - 1];

            if (this.EntryPage != null && backTypePage.SourcePageType == this.EntryPage)
            {
                e.Handled = false;
                rootFrame.BackStack.Clear();
            }
            else
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                rootFrame.GoBack();
            }
        }
```

Comment: How to manage EntryPage, because on back navigation I will not get page  type, Do I nee to set EntryPage everytime before navigation page to another?

Comment: Yes. I do Something like that. AppShell is my first page. I just register its type : NavigationHelper.Current.RegisterEntryPage(typeof(AppShell));

Comment: Thanks, but I am not using NavigationHelper in my app, and 
rootFrame.BackStack[rootFrame.BackStackDepth - 1]; will not work if scenario is like this MainPage -> Page 1 - > Page 2 -> Page 3 -> Page 1

Comment: NavigationHelper is a class I ve created. Nothing really complicated in this class. If you use myFrame.Navigate(typeof(AppShell), e.Arguments); to navigate, your BackStack collection must exist and contains your navigation

Comment: I am still confused with your suggestion, could you please post working solution, that will be much helpful